# Bootstrap, carousel cut edge

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a slide show in bootstrap with rounded corners and a shadow around the border. However the left and right edge of the carousel gets cut off and I don't know how to fix it. 
Any help is appreciated.

Here's the relevant code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Some Firm</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    #slideshow {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top:20px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
        border-radius: 25px;

    }

    </style>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="slideshow">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <center>
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="Chania">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="Chania">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="Flower">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="Flower">
            </div>
          </div>
        </center>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add padding: 0; to your #slideshow css. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: you are talking about white corners aroud the box?

Comment: @JoshSalazar no that won't work..

Comment: @JoshSalazar Thank you so much! Just what I was looking for. I feel kind of stupid for not trying that before asking...

Comment: @Jens-EmilSønderupMüller Not a problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: @Jens-EmilSønderupMüller but you have to maintain the corner as after padding you will loose them.

Comment: @Leothelion I believe by "cut off" they meant the image is being squished in from the padding making it look like it was being cut off. Removing the padding brought the image back out to the edges. It's hard to explain, here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/yksmq9pg/

Comment: @JoshSalazar i did not say bad try but before padding it has radius and after that its not coming in shape..but if op is happy then great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
#slideshow { padding:0;border-radius: 25px; }
.carousel img  { border-radius: 25px; }
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right { background:transparent; }
```

[Demo here](http://www.bootply.com/oKhbHy7RuN)

Comment: Good try but if op will use arrow for left or right then weird white gap will come. Check that.